# How do I set up dependencies for Ruby Cucumber on Windows 10?

Tags: ruby, windows, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

This is a command prompt error.

I am using the windows 10 operating system. I have to write automation script using Ruby and Cucumber. That requires devkit, ruby 2.0, sublime text.

I have created a dir for project as a "pravinpro", I have installed the cucumber gem. after running it at the command prompt, it shows error:

```
Oops... Invalid Platform
Supported platform are "android" and "iOS".
To run on Desktop no need to mention platform.
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Fqf.png)

Comment: You seem to be using the selenium-cucumber gem. Examples for that gem seem to guarantee this problem. Do you really need that gem? Its main value seems to be mobile browser support. If you're testing desktop web I'd use capybara instead; it includes selenium support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/about) for windows site? You are up against a couple of problems. The first is that Windows 10 is **not** explicitly supported. The second is the x64 version is new.  "The 64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too complicated if you just want to play with the language."

So I see two choices for you. First is to try installing the 32-bit version of ruby on Windows 10.  Then see if you have better luck with the cucumber gem.

The second is to create a virtual machine (Virtualbox is free) on your Windows 10 host.  You could install a Linux operating system, e.g. Centos 7, in the guest and run everything from there.

I have worked with Ruby on windows in mingw32 but have always found it less flexible than native on linux.  Whatever you choose, good luck.

**Update**

I got it to work on Windows 8.1. Try following these steps on Windows 10 and let me know how it went.

Downloaded 32-bit [Ruby 2.2.4](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.2.4.exe) and I extracted it to **c:\Ruby22**.

Downloaded 32-bit [Ruby Dev Kit for use with Ruby 2.0 and above](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe) and I extracted this to **c:\Ruby22DevKit**.

I created two system  environment variables (System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables) **RUBY22_HOME=C:\Ruby22** and **Ruby22_DEVKIT_HOME=C:\Ruby22DevKit**.

I updated my Path system environment variable adding to the end **;c:\Ruby22\bin;c:\Ruby22DevKit\bin**
I opened a command window and typed **bash.exe** (can be found in C:\Ruby22DevKit\bin)

```
gem install cucumber
gem install rspec-expectations
gem install capybara
gem install selenium-webdriver
```

I cd to my user home and

```
mkdir RubyCucumberProject
cd RubyCucumberProject
mkdir features
cd features
mkdir step_definitions
mkdir support
touch helloworld.feature
```

I edited **helloworld.features** adding:

```
Feature: Hello World

@helloworld
Scenario: Hello google
  Given I am on the google search page
  When I search for "hello world"
  Then there should be a result for "www.helloworld.com/"
```

I cd to **step_definitions** and **touch hello_word.rb**. I edited this file adding:

```
Given(/^I am on the google search page$/) do
  visit 'http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en'
end

When(/^I search for "(.*)"$/) do |query|
  fill_in 'as_q', :with => query
  click_button 'Search'
end

Then /^there should be a result for "(.*)"$/ do |expected_result|
  results = all('cite').map { |el| el.text }
  results.should include expected_result
end
```

I then **cd../support** so that I was in the support folder and typed **touch env.rb** edited same adding:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'rspec'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_selector = :css

World(Capybara::DSL)
```

I then **cd ../../** so that I was in the project root folder and entered **cucumber** and it worked.

Comment: I am familiar with rubyinstaller. I used: rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648, and DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx   I do same set up on windows 8.1 using 32 bit version. Then also creating same issue. As per [link] (http://seleniumcucumber.info/desktop/), I have setup correctly. Before typing cucumber command, everything is okay.

Comment: I got it working on Windows 8.1. Try my steps on Windows 10 and let me know how it went.